# Understanding "formal sum" in free abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-groups, free-abelian-group

Despite reading about formal sums and especially the last comment in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4111512/on-formal-sums-free-modules-and-free-abelian-groups) post (which seems most relevant to my question) - I still feel the need to make sure I'm not missing something:

If there is a free abelian group generated by some basis $B := \{ b_1, b_2, \dots\}$ then all that is meant by "the elements in this group are formal sums" is just that:

1. Adding any elements using the group operation "$+$" does not mean we get any other familiar element
2. **(my main issue)** $\sum_i n_i b_i$ is just shorthand for applying the group operation, e.g. $2b_1-3b_2=2(b_1-b_2)-b_2$ since it's abelian, and so we can write it in terms of the inverse of $b_2$ this way (i.e. - we're just using the group operation)? Or is there something deeper here that I'm missing?

Comment: $\sum_i n_i b_i$ isn't shorthand for applying the group operation.  It is the form of an artibrary element.  The group operatin is slotwise addition of coefficients.

Comment: @Randall Right, but just like $2b_1-3b_2$ is an element, right? And it's exactly the same element as: $2(b_1-b_2)-b_2$?

Comment: Yes.......................

Comment: It is that easy. Formal Sum invokes awe and fear while "adding variables in a normal way" doesn't impress anyone, thus the nomenclature.